# Maven Sonar How to exclude dependancy jar which are stored in local repository

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I am trying to run sonar analysis on my maven project , I have set repo in my `d:\abc` folder .
I am trying to run `mvn sonar:sonar` , however it is trying to check sources for dependency jar which is not there and due to that build is failing . 
I tried sonar.exclusions property in my `setting.xml` but that didn't help .
I could not find anything on the internet that how can we ask sonar to ignore multiple jar and just focus on source .

Following is the error message :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on
>   project abc: No files nor directories matching
>   'D:\abcrepo\com\abc\tyr\framework\security\abclogin\2.7.9-SNAPSHOT\abclogin-2.7.9-SNAPSHOT.jar'
>   in directory C:\abc\Custom\Source\Build\xyz\MavenBuild\abc_ear ->
>   [Help 1]

Sonar version is 4.5.6.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, have you tried 'sonar.sources' property?

Comma-separated paths to directories containing source files.
Compatible with Maven since SonarQube 4.2. If not set, the source code is retrieved from the default Maven source code location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried following and it worked :

```
mvn sonar:sonar -pl !../abc_ear
```

using this I was able to skip specific module which was referring to the jar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sonar.exclusions`](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-Exclusions/Inclusions) in your **pom.xml** to exclude your jar-directory :

```
<properties>
    <sonar.exclusions>first/path,second/path</sonar.exclusions>
<properties>
```